# significance and importance of spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have started recently started Operator Theory and have been introduced to the Spectral Mapping Theorem: If $a \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital Banach Algebra and $f \in \text{hol}(a)$. Then $\sigma(f(a)) = f(\sigma(a))$.

I just want to get an idea of the importance and significance of this result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Spectral Mapping Theorem allows you to more easily compute the spectrum of some operators. If you know that you can write an operator $A$ as $A=f(a)$ for $f\in hol(a)$ and $a\in\mathcal{A}$, where you already know the spectrum of $a$, you can compute the spectrum of $A$, since $\sigma(A)=f(\sigma(a))$.

Comment: So in your application $A \in \mathcal{A}$ as  well, so the usage you are implying is that if you know the spectrum of say some $a \in \mathcal{A}$, then the Spectral Mapping Theorem allows you to compute the spectrum of other members of $\mathcal{A}$ given that you have that $A = f(a)$ for some $f \in hol(a)$?

Comment: @Alex Not necessarily. It depends upon whether $f(a)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.